# Javascript no me toma las imagenes de mi pc

Tags: javascript

No puedo dar con el problema. Estoy practicando un codigo de Js y tengo alojadas en mi pc dos imagenes. Que al "llamarlas" utilizando `img.src` desde Js mediante `../` no me aparecen para seleccionarlas

Las imágenes las tengo en
‪`C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\_Practica Web\Landing Page (Efecto Luz on-off)\imagenes\Night_4.png`

`C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\_Practica Web\Landing Page (Efecto Luz on-off)\imagenes\Night_5.png`

```javascript
(()=>{
const hours = Selector(".hours");
const minutes = Selector(".minutes");
const seconds = Selector(".seconds");
const container = Selector(".container");

const checkbox = document.getElementById['switch'];
const img = document.getElementById("shops");

//setinterval method
setInterval(() => {
    const time  = new Date();
    hours.textContent = time.getHours() < 9 ? `0$(time.getHours()}`:time.getHours();
    minutes.textContent = time.getMinutes() < 9 ? `0$(time.getMinutes()}`:time.getMinutes();
    seconds.textContent = time.getSeconds() < 9 ? `0$(time.getSeconds()}`:time.getSeconds();
}, 1000);

//checkbox lights
checkbox.onchange = (event)=>{
    if(event.target.checked){
        img.src= ""                 
    }else{
 
    }        
}
})();

function Selector(element){
    return document.querySelector(element);
}
```

Comment: En que momento buscas agregar la imágen al elemento. Cuando está recién cargando la página o al ocurrir un evento, como presionar un botón, etc...

Comment: Muestra la carga de las imágenes, es muy simple suponer que cometes un error de rutas. Además, pon las imagenes en una carpeta mas accesible.

Comment: hay 2 opciones, o está cometiendo un error de rutas o está intentando cargarle la imágen al elemento antes de que se cargue el elemento en el DOM. Podrías inidicar la ruta dond se encuentra el achivo donde ejecutas el javascript

Comment: Estoy practicando quiero que al hacer click sobre un checkbox el efecto seria que se apague o prenda la luz de una imagen. Es por eso que tengo dos imagenes, una con luz y otra sin. Las imagenes las tengo en una carpeta en mi escritorio. La ruta que intento poner es img.src = "../imagenes/Night_4.png" y la ruta de la otra es img.src ="Night_5.png"